Why doesn't this inline expression `r getwd() |> strsplit('/')` work when inside the yaml header of a rmarkdown document?
I am trying to include as a subtitle in the yaml of a rmarkdown document an inline r code expression to get a part of the directory name.
So I tried this:
---
title: "Untitled"
subtitle: "`r getwd() |> str_split('/')|>pluck(1) |> pluck(7)`"
author: "Gandalf"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

The piece of code getwd() |> str_split('/')|>pluck(1) |> pluck(7) works fine in a r chunk, but when in the yaml, it does not work when knitting, and this happens after the first pipe (if I only use subtitle: "`r getwd()`" it works), e.g.this does not work:
---
title: "Untitled"
subtitle: "`r getwd() |> str_split('/')`"
author: "Gandalf"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

and I get a 'halted execution' in line 2 error message.
I tried the following which all failed:

subtitle: "`r getwd() |> stringr::str_split('/')`"
subtitle: "`r getwd() |> strsplit('/')`"

So I thought it was because of the pipe but the following actually works:
subtitle: "`r getwd() |> paste('hello')`"

The directory name looks like this: "D:/Oswaldo/Autoentrepreneur/Formateur_RStudio/Formation_Tidyverse/Sessions_clients/2024_06_24.Presentiel.Module_deb.CD_UM_fr/evaluations/satisfaction_beneficiaires"
So, what am I missing?

The stringr and purrr libraries aren't loaded when you run the code in YAML, therefore you will not have access to the str_split and pluck commands. You might need to use a base R solution.

The following should work that avoids using the pipe operator and base R strsplit():
---
title: "Untitled"
subtitle: "`r strsplit(getwd(), '/')[[1]][7]`"
author: "Gandalf"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---


When render tab in RStudio shows Execution halted, switch from Issues to Output for some further hints.
For example your getwd() |> stringr::str_split('/') and getwd() |> strsplit('/') fail as those return lists:

But as long as your calls include package names and do not return something that confuses knitr, you should be fine, i.e:
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Gandalf"
subtitle: "`r getwd() |> stringr::str_split_i('/', 7)`"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

You also have an option to split YAML block and set subtitle after you have loaded packages:
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Gandalf"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
```

---
subtitle: "`r getwd() |> str_split('/') |> pluck(1) |> pluck(7)`"
---


The fact that getwd() |> strsplit('/') returns a list is irrelevant, since that isn’t the code OP is using. OP is calling pluck(1) on the result, which returns just the first element of the list — so all is fine. The issue is that pluck() isn’t found without attacking ‘purrr’ first.

@KonradRudolph , OP listed  subtitle: "r getwd() |> strsplit('/')"` as one of the 4 failed attempts.
